# Slack notification once ECS service reach steady state

Tags: amazon-web-services, configuration, notifications, amazon-ecs, slack

Is there any way to send the slack notification to a channel, if the AWS ECS service reaches a steady state after the deployment is completed which was triggered by Jenkins

Trying to get the ECS service to a steady state and send it as a slack notification after deployment is completed.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cloudwatch_event_stream.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can utilize a combination of services to achieve this.

1. [AWS Cloudwatch Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/WhatIsCloudWatchEvents.html) to monitor for when tasks are completed. This will involve setting up something to "watch" your cluster and then it will fire once your service is in a steady state.
2. You can then integrate events with the [SNS service](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/) so you can create a topic that will follow these events.
3. You can then set up a sns subscription under an [https endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-http-https-endpoint-as-subscriber.html) that will allow you to send an event to Slack. You will probably have to create this endpoint from within your slack app and paste it in this subscription. I found an article that may help [here](https://hevodata.com/learn/sns-to-slack/).

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can. I followed the below steps

1. Select a pipeline (radio button)
2. Click on Notify button -> create notification rule
3. Notification name
4. Detail Type: Basic
5. Events: select all pipeline execution checkboxes
6. Create Target
7. Target type: AWS Chatbot (Slack)
8. Configure client (Slack)
9. Authorization
10. Configure new channel (name, logging, channel type)
11. Create an IAM role using a template
12. Role name
13. Notification permissions
14. Policy name: **AWSCodePipelineReadOnlyAccess**
15. Configure

Comment: can u pls explain in detail?

Comment: Go to CodePipeline first. Then proceed as aforementioned.

Comment: Surely this only works if you’re deploying with CodePipeline?

Comment: @AndyMadge yes, true that